# MySQL indexes on BINARY(16). What size?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I got a table with over 6.6 millions rows.

I got a field, named `trip_id` who's in `BINARY(16)`. I find my query too slow (`0.2 seconds`). This query run near once every 3 seconds.

Before doing anything stupid, I want to know if I lower the index size on `trip_id` from full to 12, would it make a difference ?

If I try to tweak my query more, would it make a difference ?

Thanks

EDIT:

Query :

```
SELECT      stop_times.stop_id
FROM        trips
LEFT JOIN   stop_times ON trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id
WHERE       trips.route_id  = '141'
GROUP BY    stop_times.stop_id
ORDER BY    trips.trip_headsign ASC,
            stop_times.stop_sequence ASC
```

`trip_id BINARY(16)`

`route_id SMALLINT(3)`

`trip_headsign VARCHAR(50)`

`stop_sequence SMALLINT(3)`

Explain of the query :
[image: Explain of the query]

Comment: 6.6 million in 0.2 seconds? Man... that's so slow I could almost blink once... Reducing index size will slow performance - it'll use the index for 12 bytes, then table-scan to figure out the other 4 bytes.

Comment: @dystroy I updated to include my query. Marc linking require 6/100, 0.2 may be acceptable but when this query is gonna run under an android application this is gonna be more slower. I know this can go faster.

Comment: @MarcB Depends on what the ID is. If it's random like a GUID, there's a pretty good chance most of the time the first (or any) 12 bytes taken are unique as well.

Comment: @millimoose 6.6 millions rows in MD5 hash ... so yes first 12 bytes repeat itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing researches, I've found the problem because yes, 0.2 seconds is slow.

```
SELECT      t.trip_headsign, st.stop_sequence, s.stop_code, s.stop_name
FROM        stop_times AS st
JOIN        stops AS s USING (stop_id)
JOIN        (   SELECT  trip_id,
                        route_id,
                        trip_headsign
                FROM    trips
                WHERE   route_id = '141'
                LIMIT   2
            ) AS t
WHERE       t.trip_id = st.trip_id
GROUP BY    st.stop_id
```

First, instead of doing a `LEFT JOIN`, `JOIN` is faster here. But the important point, I was matching all results from trips in the WHERE statement.

However, since a bus can only have 2 directions, I only have to limit my results to 2. Now, my results are near 0.018. Over 1000% improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 'Using temporary' and 'Using filesort' in your 'Extra' column.

These are surefire signs that you could improve things. The reason that these are showing up is because of your GROUP and ORDER clauses.

First step: are they truly necessary? You may find that, end to end, it's cheaper to sort them with the language that consumes this data.

Second step: if you still need `ORDER BY`, then take a look at [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) in the MySQL docs. The reason that an index is not used for sorting here is the differing `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Think outside of the box. You're not doing any aggregation, so maybe grouping isn't necessary. Maybe just pull all of the rows and then ignore the duplicated ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding trip_headsign to your "route" index.  Because you are using that in the ORDER BY, mysql needs to go to the actual table to fetch it for every record it finds in the index that matches the route_id.  If you don't see "Using index" in the Extra column of the explain, that means MySQL is forced to go back to the actual table to get additional information.